# How to disable sending messages to people with closed DM

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

So I don't want to send messages to people with closed DM's.

Current Code:

```
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  if (member.id !== bot.user.id && !member.user.bot);
  member.send(message);
});
```

Comment: Before that, there's already a problem: your semicolon ends your `if` statement without making it guard anything, so it will always send.

Comment: I tested it, it sends only once

Comment: The code written will send to every member, even bots. You seem to have tried to write code to skip bots, but the `if` is wrongly terminated before the `send()` and does nothing.

Comment: It's working properly, It's not sending messages to bots, so now I want to block sending messages to people with closed dm

Comment: The code you posted cannot filter out bots because it doesn't properly skip sending to them. I don't know how many ways I can say this. If it fails to send to bots, that'll just be because they reject DMs and you don't check whether an exception was thrown indicating your `if` didn't work. See [Discord.js How to check if the user does not accept Direct Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621884/discord-js-how-to-check-if-the-user-does-not-accept-direct-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you can't check if someone has DMs open, at least at this moment. What you **can** do is send the message and catch the error if someone has DMs closed.

Also, you put a semicolon right after the if, which basically voids the purpose of the if statement. Remove the semicolon and it should not send to any bots.

For example:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  if (member.id !== bot.user.id && !member.user.bot) // remove the semicolon here
  member.send(message).catch(() => {}); // catch an error if the user has their DMs closed
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, I don't know why I added semicolon in the first place, but yea, thanks for helping me, at least I can do it like that <3

Comment: Is there a way now in 2023, to check if the user has a dm open or not? As far as I have researched, there still isn't an official way. But I would like to know if there is any other workaround in 2023.